# how to replace parts of search string in R

Tags: regex, r

```
string <- c("tyuynmklabcwsqzp")
```

If my task is to substitute every "abc" with "abc123", the code is,

```
gsub("abc", "\\1123", string)
```

But, if I have to search for "abc" and then replace it with "c123", then how should I do it? Is there a way to divide the regular expression into parts so that I can have \2 like \1?
If it's possible, then my command would be,

```
gsub("abc", "\\2123", string).
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parentheses to group together parts of a regular expression, subsequently applying a repetition operator or backreference to the matched group.

In your case, try this:

```
string <- c("tyuynmklabcwsqzp")
gsub("(ab)(c)", "\\2123", string)
# [1] "tyuynmklc123wsqzp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
gsub("(abc)", "\\1123", string)   # abc → abc123
```

and

```
gsub("ab(c)", "\\1123", string)   # abc → c123
```